# Why do I receive characters at an offset in the buffer when using ReadFile()?

Tags: c, winapi, avr, serial-communication

### What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to write win console which will communicate with my ATMega2560 board via UART. Now it should send string saved in `stringToSend` to the MCU which should be send back to the PC. String sent from MCU should be saved in `receivedString` and then written to the win console window.

### What the code does:

What it does now is that after I send the string to MCU it will come back, but on the console I see an unexpected sequence of '╠' characters preceding the echoed string, just like this:

> You sent:
>
> ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Sended test string!

---

EDIT: Number of characters is consistent if `BUFFER_SIZE` is constant, but it scales with `BUFFER_SIZE`:

- If `BUFFER_SIZE = 124` then there's **132** of these characters
- If `BUFFER_SIZE = 1024` then there's **1032** of these characters
- If `BUFFER_SIZE = 1` then there's **9** of these characters

---

### Weird things (probably just for me):

- The weirdest thing is that when I use breakpoints and look into `receivedString` the string from `stringToSend` isn't there BUT it will appear in the console.
- When I send data via Termite (console for sending data via serial communication) the problem disappear and after that I'm receiving ONLY the right string even with my console.

### The questions:

- Am I supposed to setup some bit/flag in the MCU which cause this behavior?
- May it be problem with format of the string?
- Am I just completely missing something what I should do before/after I send the data from PC/MCU?

### What did I try:

- I tried to find some solution on internet but I can't find nothing
- As experimentation I tried nothing because honestly I'm completely clueless what the problem could be

I would really appreciate any help even with refactoring/other coding tips.

---

### Answers to comments:

1. Could you print values as hexadecimal and add number of these elements?

> The output:
>
> ```
> ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc >ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc >ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc >ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc >ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc ffffffcc 53 65 6e 64 65 64 20 74 65 73 74 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67 21
> ```
>
> Number of these characters is always `BUFFER_SIZE + 8` and the character in decimal is represented as `-52`

---

### Solution:

- I already added 4th parameter into functions `WriteFile()` and `ReadFile()` and the problem wasn't there (but it definitely can cause some problems because documentation says the last two parameters can't be both NULL).
- I found somewhere in documentation that `ReadFile()` should always come after event occurs and function `WaitCommEvent()` catch it. The type of event is set by `SetCommMask(mainCom, EV_RXCHAR)` so it occur when there's character in input buffer (there's documentation to function [SetCommMask()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommmask)). This solution shows **the error is caused by the board** which doesn't send the data because `WaitCommEvent()` will end up in infinite loop waiting for receiving data. However without using `WaitCommEvent()` it seems like the sent data are held by some kind of memory and read from there so even when the board doesn't send them, they're printed (I really don't understand why but see [@thebusybee answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075752/20952714)). What actually repair the problem is just simple reconnecting the board every time I boot windows (after reconnecting is everything functional even with using `WaitCommEvent()`) which leads me into completely different question if windows is sending some weird stuff into USB ports when booting so it mess with the board but that's for another topic. It could by also caused by windows using different communication parameters (as baud rate etc.) while booting. But that's for another/different question.

Comment: You have two "newline"s in your format string for the output: `"\nYou sent: \n\n%s\n\n"`. This inserts an empty line.

Comment: @thebusybee So I edited question and to clarify, my problem are these `╠` before the correct string not empty lines.

Comment: I note that `receivedString` is declared with 124 elements, but more than 124 characters are being printed in the in the slot represented by the corresponding `%s` in the output format.  However, I don't see any reason why the `ReadFile()` call presented would read that many bytes.  It might be worthwhile to use the fourth parameter of `ReadFile()` to get that function's own idea of how many bytes it read.

Comment: Is the number of `╠` characters consistent from run to run?

Comment: I don't know whether it is significant, but your `stringToSend` array ends with *two* null characters (one explicit in the initializer and one implicit).  You write both to the serial port, and allow for reading both back.  However, the MCU code expects only one null or newline character to terminate a message, and it will send back only one (per message).

Comment: @JohnBollinger So I quickly tested how many characters are there and yes, It's consistent but if I change `BUFFER_SIZE` then there will appear more of them so It's increasing with `BUFFER_SIZE`. For the info if `BUFFER_SIZE = 124` then there's __132__ these characters. When I increase the value to `BUFFER_SIZE = 1024` then there's __1032__ of these characters. If I change `stringToSend[] = "A\0"` and decrease `BUFFER_SIZE = 1` then there's __9__ of these characters.

Comment: So it's `BUFFER_SIZE + 8`, then.  Interesting.  That very much suggests that the problem is on the Windows side, because the buffer size is never communicated to the MCU.

Comment: I don't think it should be necessary in this case, but what if you declare `receivedString` with an initializer?  `char receivedString[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};`

Comment: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile), the fourth and fifth parameters to `ReadFile()` cannot both be null.

Comment: So If I initialize `receivedString` like that it will return nothing and at the end of the program `receivedString` just string full of `\0`

Comment: What seems to be happening is that the data read by `ReadFile()` are going to the wrong place -- 8 bytes after the end of the `receivedString` buffer.  I don't know why that would be, but do not overlook my previous comment about the parameters to `ReadFile()` -- the last two should not both be null.  The same applies to `WriteFile()`, too.

Comment: You might need to [edit] the title as well, because it prominently asks about this empty line and says nothing on the real problem.

Comment: Well, thanks for your try. Unfortunately it says just the same in other words. But your real issue is not the empty line, this is clear from your format string. The real issue is the wrong place the received string is stored, as you in the meantime revealed. Would you mind to edit it again?

Comment: @thebusybee Can you please tell me how would you title this problem? Honestly I was thinking just like "What I was searching to find the solution before I asked question here" and that's it. I have no problem with editing I just really don't know how to name it better

Comment: What do you think of "Why do I receive characters at an offset in the buffer when using ReadFile()?" and tags for winapi and serial-communication?

Comment: Sounds good to me so I changed it, hope now is everything alright. Thanks for helping me with that

Comment: `receivedString, sizeof( stringToSend )` - copy/pasta bug? Should be `sizeof( receivedString )`. You also didn't check how many bytes were read. I suspect that zero bytes were read, so you are printing uninitialized data.

Comment: @RaymondChen This function parametr is telling maximum possible amount of bytes which will be read that's why it's alright because in this example I'm trying to send string so I can't read more bytes then I sent.

Comment: Why, @RaymondChen?  The program indeed expects to receive `sizeof( stringToSend )` bytes.  If `stringToSend` were larger than `receivedString` then that would be an issue, but it's not.

Comment: Another experiment: Instead of printing the received characters as a single string, would you mind to print each of them as hex? And the number of received characters? It could be helpful to see the bytes that are rendered here as `╠`.

Comment: You're lucky that `sizeof(stringToSend)` is less than `BUFFER_SIZE`. If you really intended to receive only `sizeof(stringToSend)` bytes, then why is the size of `receivedString` unrelated to `sizeof(stringToSend)`? Someday, you'll make `stringToSend` bigger, and then `receivedString` will not be big enough and you get a buffer overflow and a CVE.

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh yes, you definetly got point there. I didn't realize that I'm actually making the string just for 124 chars so it may overflow really easily. Thank's for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadFile()` does not read any bytes from the serial device because of your erroneous call with both last parameters set to `NULL`. However, `ReadFile()` did not return `FALSE`.

The values 0xCC (printed sign-extended as 0xFFFFFFCC) that are filled into `receivedString` are [used as debug aid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370362/11294831).

Your PC's compiler apparently locates the variable `receivedString` *before* the variable `stringToSend` on the stack. The additional bytes are most probably [canary words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries).

When you now print `receivedString`, the function `printf` scans through the memory until it finds a terminating `'\0'`. This is the case *after* the contents of `stringToSend` was scanned additionally and copied to the output. So what you see is *not received* by `ReadFile()`, but the *existing* characters of `stringToSend`, which happens to be exactly what you expect to receive.

This visualizes the memory situation:

| (lower address)... | `receivedString` | padding | `stringToSend` | ...(higher address) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0xCC, 0xCC, ... 0xCC | 0xCC, ... 0xCC | 'S', 'e', ... '!', '\0' |  |

What should you do?

1. Never ignore any return and output values. Check the number of actually read bytes, in this case.
2. Always read the documentation of a function and use it accordingly. Commonly, and I'm afraid to say this, especially on Windows, the principle "[garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)" holds true.